# Togglz support with Spring boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, togglz

I am adding Togglz to my existing spring boot 3 application. I can not read the state of the enum constants from application.yml or any other property files. Only way state can be changed is by annotating @EnableByDefault. I followed the link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-togglz for reference implementation.
Has anyone successfully configured Togglz with Spring Boot3?

Answer (score 1):

At the time this question was asked, Togglz only supported Spring Boot 3 in milestone released. Since then, Togglz v4.0.0 has been released, which supports Spring Boot 3: https://github.com/togglz/togglz/releases/tag/4.0.0.